# Groovy closure without preceding equal sign prop = {} vs prop {}

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to create a config file for my java app that can have lazy evaluation, for instance, contain an e-mail template with current date time. I use `ConfigSlurper` to parse the config file.

For some reason I can't find at https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html the description of the commonly used form (see `build.gradle`): `prop1 { ... } prop2 { ... }`. Am I looking at the wrong place?

My tests show that such closures are evaluated immediately and the example above can be rewritten as: `prop1 = { ... }() prop2 = { ... }()` (notice the parentheses, without them the evaluation is lazy).

I also don't understand why using dots in property without the equal sign cause `MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.URL()` if I use: `server.URL { System.out.println('ccc'); 'asd' }` in the example below.

It's disappointing that the choice is completely transparent for Groovy, but you have to check that a value is instance of `Closure` or `GString` when using java.

I used this article as the starting point https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/grassroots-groovy-configuration-with.html

```
// We can group settings.
// The following settings are created:
// app.version, app.setting1, app.setting2, app.setting3, app.date, app.active
app {
    System.out.println('aaa')
    version = "1.0"
     
    // We can write code to set up settings.
    [1, 2, 3].each {
        this."setting${it}" = it * 10
    }
     
    // We can use Java objects
    date = new Date()
    active = true
}
 
server.URL = "http://default"
 
// Environment specific settings override settings with the
// same name.
environments {
    development {
        server = { System.out.println('ccc'); 'asd' }
//        server.URL = "${-> System.out.println('bbb');new Date()}http://localhost"
    }
    test {
        server.URL = 'http://test:9080'
    }
    integrationtest {
        server.URL = 'http://integrationtest/url'
    }
    production {
        server.URL = 'http://prod/url'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My tests show that such closures are evaluated immediately and the
> example above can be rewritten as: prop1 = { ... }()

Closures are not evaluated immediately.  The parens above are causing the closure to be evaluated.

> For some reason I can't find at https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html
> the description of the commonly used form (see build.gradle): prop1 {
> ... } prop2 { ... }.

`prop1 {}` is invoking a method named `prop1` and passing a closure as a parameter  That code is equivalent to this:

```
def myClosure = {}

prop1(myClosure)
```

> I also don't understand why using dots in property without the equal
> sign cause MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> groovy.util.ConfigObject.URL()

Something like `server.URL = 'http://test:9080'` is assigning a value (http://test:9080) to a property (server.URL).  If you remove the equal sign you are changing the expression fundamentally and then would be invoking a method named URL on an object named `server` and passing http://test:9080 as a parameter.

Comment: You. may be confused that closures are automatically evaluated because the context in which you are doing this is one where the builder will invoke the closure on your behalf in order to populate the config map.  It is not the case that closures are evaluated immediately.  If you do `def c = { }`, that closure will never be evaluated unless you write code to cause that to happen.